# Looking for assistance in Excel to return X number of values for a vlookup

Tags: excel

I have a dataset that includes the following information:

Storage Location Tab

- Column A - product identifier (can be repeated)
- Column B - storage location (unique)

Quantity needed tab

- Column A - product identifier
- Column B - # of products needed (X)

I'm looking to use a vlookup type of equation to return the first X number (# of products needed) of storage locations results of the product identifier (as vlookup by default would only show the first result)

Comment: Does your version of Excel support FILTER?

Comment: Do a search for top 5 or top 10 on here - or check out aggregate().

Answer (score 0):

Well, like others have said the built in filtering is the easiest way to do this. But, if you MUST only return the first x items, you can do the following which will require a tiny change to your data:

1.) Add one additional column in your "Storage Location Tab" to keep track of the item index ( for example if it is the 3rd item with product identifier = 5 in column A, you assign it item index 3)

You can do this with the following function on C2 and just drag it down: =COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2).

This formula will essentially just count how many rows have the same product ID above it (including itself).

2.) Next, In your other Tab where you want to return x results, create an "item index" also. This is to for searching purposes and to keep track of the item you want to extract from the table. If you want to pull the first 4 items you essentially need to do a look up for items (1, 2, 3,& 4)

With those additional fields you can use a combination of the "index" and "match" functions to do a search on 2 criteria "Product identifier" and "Item index" to get your storage locations.

=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,(A:A=$F$2)*(C:C=E3),0),0)

Here is what my excel looks like to assist with a visual:
[My Excel Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhlEC.png)

If you want to add some error checks and make it so it does not return anything for indexes greater than your "# of products needed" then you can wrap the above formula with an if statement and an if error statement. The below will return an empty space if the match returns no results or the item index is larger than the # of products needed.

=IF($G$2>=E3,IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,(A:A=$F$2)*(C:C=E3),0),0),""),"")